# PHP Error while adding the rows

Tags: php, mysql, addition

I want to add the amount in all rows.Here is the code.Please help me.

```
$tot1=mysql_query("select SUM(Amount) from wp_product_details"); 
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($tot1))
{
echo $row1['Amount'];
}
```

Comment: Did you try $row['SUM(Amount)']?

Comment: Try this instead:  `select SUM(Amount) as Amount from wp_product_details`

Comment: And did you try this query : `SELECT SUM(Amount) AS Amount FROM wp_product_details`

Comment: there is no result in this code

Answer (score 2):

Change your query a little to use amount with `$row1[]`

```
$tot1=mysql_query("select SUM(Amount) as Amount from wp_product_details");
```

Or change your `$row1[]` syntax

```
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($tot1))
{
echo $row1['SUM(Amount)'];
}
```

Comment: try this sql query in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 $tot1=mysql_query("select SUM(Amount) as amount from wp_product_details"); 
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($tot1))
    {
    echo $row1['amount'];
    }
```

Comment: `select SUM(Amount) as amount from wp_product_details` execute this query in your sqlclient and check if you are getting any result.and do check you dtaabase cnnection too.